# I need help in converting urlpatterns url to their path equivalents

Tags: python, django

I am helping a friend with a project and I am having trouble converting urlpatterns url to their path equivalents. Any help?

I've managed the first part.

```
path('store', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
```

But the rest seems challenging

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^store', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Why is it challenging? Path syntax is intended to be simpler than regexes, what exactly are you finding difficult? Note also that regex continue to be supported with the `re_path` function which is basically just `url` renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the path converters as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters). In your case you will need `int` and `slug`, so something like this:

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

Comment: @FredrickKemosi I hope you also understand how and why it works ;)